# Navigate focus using up/down key

Tags: javascript, html

I have this little javascript tool that converts numbers into other bases in real time. It does this by calling an update function `checkchangedec()`, `checkchangehex()` and so forth each time a key is pressed in each of the text boxes. It works fine.

What I want to be able to do is 'move the focus' using the arrow keys. I have successfully done this before, using `event.keyCode`, but the problem is I am already calling function using the element's onkeydown and onkeypressed. I am not aware of a way of calling multiple functions through onkeydown or onkeypressed attributes.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/murtaza64/wrrGW/4/) is a JSFiddle of the number converter
specifically, here is the input:

`<input id="dec" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" onkeydown=checkchangedec() value="10">`

and the functions it calls:

```
function checkchangedec() {
setTimeout(

    function () {
        if (id('dec').value !== "") {
            id('hex').value = parseInt(id('dec').value, 10).toString(16);
            id('bin').value = parseInt(id('dec').value, 10).toString(2);
            id('cbi').value = parseInt(id('dec').value, 10).toString(id('cbival').value);
        }
    }, 20);
}   


function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
}
return true;
```

}

[Here](http://atestingsite.com/buildabox.html) is an example of how I got this to work:

```
function navigate(up, down) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 40) document.getElementById(down).focus(); 
            if (event.keyCode == 38) {document.getElementById(up).focus(); document.getElementById(up).select();}
            if (event.keyCode == 39) randomize(); // the randomize() function gives a random number, 
                                                  // irrelevant to navigation
```

Here is the input box:

`<input type="text" value="55EEFF" id="i_sco" onkeydown="navigate('i_col', 'i_ssi')"></input>`

Comment: Thanks :D I love programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I am not aware of a way of calling multiple functions through onkeydown or onkeypressed attributes."

You can get the same result by defining a new "wrapper" function that contains all the other functions you want to call when the event occurs. Then, just assign this new function to the `onkeypress` event.

HTML:

```
<input id="dec" onkeypress="click_function()" value="10">
```

JavaScript:

```
function click_function(event) {
    //first make sure a number key was pressed
    if(isNumberKey(event)) {
        checkchangedec();

        return true;
    } else
        //you can check event.keyCode again here for up/down
    }

    return false;  //will return false if a number key was not pressed
}
```

Does that help get you started in solving your problem?

Comment: Thanks. This works for the calling of functions, except the navigation isn't working.

Comment: `function click_function_dec(event) {
    //first make sure a number key was pressed
    if(isNumberKey(event)) {
        checkchangedec();
    } else
       if(event.keyCode == 40)
           id('hex').focus;
           id('hex').select; //you can check event.keyCode again here for up/down
    

    return false;  //will return false if a number key was not pressed

}` is what I tried and the functions call fine but the navigation doesn't work. I did modify my HTML.

Comment: @murtaza64 here's an updated fiddle with the decimal box working how you want it to: http://jsfiddle.net/64Qs5/ - the trick is to assign just one event handler to the `<input>`, for the `onkeydown` event. in that event, i first check if the down key is pressed (using a `DOWN_KEY` variable i created to make it easy to remember), then if it wasn't, i check if a number key was pressed. if so, `return true`, otherwise `return false`.

Comment: @murtaza64 also, hint: i called the event handler function `check_input` because you can use the same function for all the inputs if you modify it a bit. within the function, you can get the id of the element clicked using `this.id`. The `this` variable is special; it represents the element that fired the event - in this case, the input box. BUT, in your current code this won't work unless you rename your `id` function. because it's a global function, javascript won't be able to access the built-in `this.id` property.

Comment: @murtaza64 and here's a full working example that cuts down on the amount of code, if you're interested: http://jsfiddle.net/XDGvF/

Comment: Thank you so much sgroves. Just one question: how does this line of code work:

Comment: `return !((charCode > 31) && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57));` I think it returns false if the statement is true. Am I correct?

Comment: you're correct. i rewrote those into one-liners because there's no reason to use an `if` statement when you're just returning `true` or `false`. it's just personal preference, really, but i figured you might not have seen it before.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the functionality you want by modifying your `checkchangedec`, `checkchangehex` etc. functions

HTML:

```
<input id="dec" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" onkeydown="checkchangedec(event)" value="10">
```

Javascript:

```
function checkchangedec(event)
{
var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
if (charCode == 40){
    var input = document.getElementById('hex');
    input.focus();
    input.select();
    return;
}
else if (charCode == 38)
    return; // there isn't an input above Decimal.

setTimeout(
    function () {
        if (id('dec').value !== "") {
            id('hex').value = parseInt(id('dec').value, 10).toString(16);
            id('bin').value = parseInt(id('dec').value, 10).toString(2);
            id('cbi').value = parseInt(id('dec').value, 10).toString(id('cbival').value);
        }
    }, 20);

}
```

Comment: I replaced the `checkchangedec` function with exactly that but the arrow keys still aren't working. Thanks for help.